# How to fix 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#

Message Error:

> 'Input string was not in a correct format.'\

```
private void dgvProduct_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string colName = dgvProduct.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
        if(colName == "Edit")
        {
            Qty qty = new Qty(cashier);
            qty.ProductDetails(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), double.Parse(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].ToString()), cashier.lblTransactionNo.Text, int.Parse(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].ToString()));
            qty.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

```
qty.ProductDetails(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), double.Parse(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].ToString()), cashier.lblTransactionNo.Text, int.Parse(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].ToString()));
```

problem is in this line but i cant see where

Comment: Use double.TryParse() to detect invalid user input.

Comment: I recommend that, instead of writing everything in one line, you use several lines with appropriately-named variables to do things in small pieces. That way, it's easy to see what's meant to be happening and you would be able to narrow down the problem to a much smaller area.

Answer (score 2):

It's here:

```
double.Parse(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].ToString()), cashier.lblTransactionNo.Text, int.Parse(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].ToString())
```

Specifically this:

```
double.Parse(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].ToString())
```

or this:

```
 int.Parse(dgvProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].ToString())
```

One of these items has a value that will not convert properly. Remember: this includes empty strings. You cannot parse an empty to string to an int or double value.

---

One additional note:

The values in these cells will either *already be strings*, in which case it's **silly** to call `.ToString()`, or they will *already be number types*, in which case it's *also silly* to call `.ToString()` (or parse the values at all).